# Notification from NodeJs to React client doesn't work (Server-Sent-Events)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-sent-events, eventsource

I'm trying to send a notification to my React UI anytime someone access my NodeJs request.
The request is the following:

```
 app.get('/notification', (req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
          });
            
           
        if(req.query.id == 'audio')
        {
            res.write(`data: TEST\n\n`);
            res.write("\n\n");
        }

        res.end();

  })
  .listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:5000/");
  });
```

In my component constructor ( App ) I used a EventSource as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.eventSource = new EventSource( 'http://' + CONSTANTS.IP_API +':5000/notification');
    this.eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
    };
 }
```

However, as you may have guessed, it doesn't work.

I don't know if this is the expected way EventSource works and if I didn't understand the point, but when calling `http://localhost:5000/notification?id=audio`, I see my result displayed as a response but this result doesn't show up in the UI console. It seems the EventSource listener doesn't catch it...

The listener tries to connect every second but I need a real time listener. Is EventSource appropriate for this? Or should I use socket.io instead?

Thanks in advance, and forgive me if this sounds trivial, I'm beginning with NodeJs and react :)